# Powershell Check versions number of installed program

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to get this code to work, but i cant get the version to match - can you help?

```
$Version = Get-ChildItem hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} | Where-Object {
$_.PSChildName -Eq '{BFAE8D5B-F918-486F-B74E-90762DF11C5C}'} | Select-Object Version

Write-Host $Version

if ($Version -eq 67436760)
{
    Write-Host "Version match"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Not Matched"
}
```

Comment: You could simply add the **-ExpandProperty** switch to `Select-Object -Version`, in order to return the contents of the **Version** property rather than an object containing that property. The help for this property is unclear, but I just posted [an answer to another question that explains the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24535790/1248365)...which has an inaccuracy I just noticed, but I'll fix that momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to compare an object to an integer. Since it's the wrong data type you will always get False returned.

To fix this you simply need add `.Version`, like this:

```
if ($Version.Version -eq 67436760)
{
    Write-Host "Version match"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Not Matched"
}
```

That will retrieve the integer inside the object instead of the object itself.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

you need to capture that version variable better and convert it to an interger.  Use:

```
Write-Host $Version
[int]$Version=$Version.version
```

Comment: It's not really necessary to cast it as an integer. The **Version** property already is an integer.