# How to display all items in a member from Powershell without "..."

Tags: powershell

Run the following command:

```
Get-ADUser <username> -properties MemberOf | select MemberOf | Format-List *
```

results in something like

```
MemberOf : {CN=XXX,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=com, CN=XXX,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=com,CN=XXX,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=com,...}
```

I do not want to see "..." I actually want to see all the items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **Select-Object**'s **-ExpandProperty** switch:

```powershell
Get-ADUser <username> -Properties MemberOf | select -ExpandProperty MemberOf
```

When you use **Select-Object** to filter for certain properties, it returns a PSCustomObject containing the specified properties of the object selected (or an array of PSCustomObjects, if multiple objects are selected). With **-ExpandProperty**, which may be used with only a single property, for each object selected it returns the object contained in the specified property.

So, with `| select MemberOf`, what's being returned is a PSCustomObject whose sole property is the **MemberOf** property of the ADUser object returned by **Get-ADUser**, displayed in list format (in the same style as it would display the results if you were listing multiple properties of the object).

With `| select -ExpandProperty MemberOf`, what's being returned is the ADPropertyCollection object which is contained in the **MemberOf** property (a collection of strings representing the DNs of the members), and that's the object that's displayed in list format.

BTW, I removed the `| Format-List *` because it's superfluous in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately you'd never guess that **-ExpandProperty** is what you're looking for from reading the help, because the help for that property is so poorly written -- how are you supposed to know what "an attempt should be made to expand that property" is supposed to mean? BTW, I just noticed an inaccuracy in the original answer, which I've corrected. **Select-Object** without **-ExpandProperty** doesn't return the original object type, it returns a PSCustomObject with the selected properties of the selected object.

Answer (score 1):

Adi Inbar is correct. Let me expand on this by saying if you're having issues, often `get-member` is very useful for figuring out what is going on.

```
PS C:\> ipmo ActiveDirectory
PS C:\> Get-ADUser testuser42 | select memberof | gm


   TypeName: Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
memberof    NoteProperty Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection memberof=Microsoft.ActiveDir...
```

Comment: Yes, Get-Member is often useful for figuring out what is going on... but your comment about it is not :-) I really have no idea what point you are trying to convey here with respect to @Steven's question.