# Pwershell.registry search items value where its diplayname like " "

Tags: powershell, get, registry, key

With help of Powershell I need to find registry key, where Value Displayname like '*Cisco*', and get from this key data from Value name 'Uninstallstring'.
I know this sounds somewhat strange, but this application has a different uninstall string on each computer.

So

```powershell
ForEach-Object -InputObject (Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall') {
  $single_item = $_ | Get-Item
  $single_item_properties = $single_item | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object -Property DisplayName,UninstallString | Where-Object {($_.DisplayName -like '*Cisco*TSP*')}
  $uninstall_str = ($single_item_properties | Select UninstallString)
  $str_to_execute=$uninstall_str.UninstallString  -replace '" .*','"'
  $str_to_execute
  Start-Process -FilePath $str_to_execute -ArgumentList '-s','-f1"\\sandbox\Common.Installs\Utils\un.iss"' -Wait -PassThru
}
```

This script gives us the error

> UninstallString
>
> ---
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information{01A05F96-E34D-4308-965C-65DCA4AF114D}\setup.exe"
>
> Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.

The problem is that the result is in not String type.

And I can't convert it into String.

Comment: BTW, in editing your question I noticed that it's not clear if you really need a loop at all. Is it possible that multiple keys might match `*Cisco*TSP*`, and you want to execute the uninstall commands for all of them, or is there going to be only one on each computer? In the latter case, I don't see the need to use either **ForEach-Object** or **foreach**, since you're only retrieving the data of a single string value from the registry.

Comment: On each computer where i want to run this script installed only one Cisco product, thus search query should work

Comment: On second thought, you still need the iteration, since you don't know the name of the key and need to find it with a **where** filter. However, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here.

1. Although **ForEach-Object** *does* have the **-InputObject** parameter, it's primarily designed to take pipeline input. As the documentation says,

   > When you use the InputObject parameter with ForEach-Object, instead of piping command results to ForEach-Object, the InputObject value—even if the value is a collection that is the result of a command, such as –InputObject (Get-Process)—is treated as a single object. Because InputObject cannot return individual properties from an array or collection of objects, it is recommended that if you use ForEach-Object to perform operations on a collection of objects for those objects that have specific values in defined properties, you use ForEach-Object in the pipeline

   In your code, the scriptblock gets executed only once, and **$single_item** is actually an array containing the entire output of **Get-ChildItem**. In order to iterate over the results one element at a time, you need to either pipe the output to **ForEach-Object**...

   ```powershell
   Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\...' | ForEach-Object {
   ```

   ...or better yet, use the **foreach** control structure, which generally runs faster (though it uses more memory):

   ```powershell
   foreach ($single_item in (Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\...')) {
   ```
2. Piping each element to **Get-Item** is superfluous. You can pipe directly to **Get-ItemProperty**.
3. You don't need to select a property in order to filter on it with **Where-Object**. So, it's superfluous to use `Select-Object -Property DisplayName,UninstallString`, which creates a PSCustomObject with two properties, and then retrieve the **UninstallString** property of that PSCustomObject later in the code. Just filter with **Where-Object** first, then get the value of **UninstallString** with `| Select -ExpandProperty UninstallString`.

   (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535790/1248365) for an explanation of the reason for using the **-ExpandPropery** switch.)
4. Using **-ExpandProperty**, you'll get errors if any keys are returned that do not have an **UninstallString** property, so you might want to add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to your **Select-Object** statement.

Putting it all together:

```powershell
foreach ($single_item in (Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall')) {
  $uninstall_str = $single_item `
  | Get-ItemProperty `
  | ?{$_.DisplayName -like '*Cisco*TSP*'} `
  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UninstallString -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  $str_to_execute = $uninstall_str -replace '" .*','"'
  Start-Process -FilePath $str_to_execute -ArgumentList '-s','-f1"\\sandbox\Common.Installs\Utils\un.iss"' -Wait -PassThru }
}
```

If there's guaranteed to be no more than one matching item, you can do it more compactly like this:

```powershell
$str_to_execute = (
  Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall' `
  | Get-ItemProperty `
  | ?{$_.DisplayName -like 'Microsoft*'}
).uninstallstring $uninstall_str -replace '" .*','"'
```

The more compact version will actually work even if there are multiple matching keys in PowerShell v3+, but in v2 it would return null if there's more than one.

BTW, **?** is an abbreviation for **Where-Object**. Similarly, **%** is an abbreviation for **ForEach-Object** (only if you use it as a filter in a pipeline, but that's how you *should* be using it anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

The output you show does not seem to match the code you provided. When I execute your code I get the `uninstallstring` based on my own search. When I first saw the output I thought "*Oh... he forgot that he was passing an object with a property UninstallString to Start-Process*". But when I looked at your code I could see that you accounted for that by doing `$uninstall_str.UninstallString`. So I am not sure what is exactly wrong but one improvement would be to use `-ExpandProperty` of `Select-Object`

```
$uninstall_str = $single_item_properties | Select -ExpandProperty UninstallString
$str_to_execute=$uninstall_str -replace '" .*','"'
```

But we can make a one liner if you prefer.

```
$str_to_execute = ($single_item_properties).UninstallString -replace '" .*','"'
```